# The marker is not display using Geofire

Tags: android-studio

I am using Geofire to display all buses near by the users all getting well but the marker is not showing in map when the key is enter here is my code

```
    List<Marker> markerslist = new ArrayList<>();

private void getbusesatlocation() {


    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(("tracker"));
    final GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(databaseReference);
    GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(20.899580, 77.750101), 1000);

    geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {

            Log.i("key", key);
            for (Marker marker : markerslist) {
                if (marker.getTag().equals(key))
                    return;

            }
            LatLng buslocation = new LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude);
            Marker mMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(buslocation).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA)));
            mMarker.setTag(key);
            markerslist.add(mMarker);


        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyExited(String key) {

            Log.i("exited", key);
            for (Marker marker : markerslist) {
                if (marker.getTag().equals(key)) {
                    marker.remove();
                    markerslist.remove(marker);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {

            Log.i("moving", key);

            for (Marker marker : markerslist) {
                if (marker.getTag().equals(key)) {

                    marker.setPosition(new LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude));
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryReady() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

I have checked onkey is giving me latitude and longitude but when i am adding the marker in map the marker is not showing please help me

Comment: Please give answer above question the mMap.addMarker() is not working in Onkeyenterd in geofire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem just using old dependency of Geofire.I do not know what is happening with new version of geofire but this version is working fine for me `implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-java:2.3.1'` ;)